# VARCHAR(MAX) acting weird when concatenating string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a concatenating query:

```
DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(max) 
SELECT @path = ISNULL(@path + '/', '') + url_segment 
    FROM navigation_self_and_parents(2813) ORDER BY depth ASC
SELECT @path
```

`navigation_self_and_parents(2813)` returns

> ```
> id    par_id  title        url_segment    sequence        depth
> 2813  2816    testing1234  testing1234    0               0   
> 2816  2809    U            /fixedurl      0               -1   
> 2809  NULL    E            E              0               -2
> ```

My concatenating query returns

```
'testing1234'             when using `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and
'E//fixedurl/testing1234' when using `NVARCHAR(4000)`
```

My best guess is that using `NVARCHAR(MAX)` causes @path to be retyped every time it's set and thus losing the contents set prior to retyping or it's typed the first time it's set and then subsequent concatenating calls silently fail.

I would love to truly understand the root cause of this behavior though.

**UPDATE**

navigation_self_and_parents:

```
USE [SomeDatabase]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[navigation_self_and_parents]
(   
    @id int
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    WITH navigation_self_and_parents (id, parent_id, title, url_segment, sequence_number, depth)
    AS
    (
        SELECT id, parent_id, title, url_segment, sequence_number, 0 FROM navigation_node WHERE id=@id 
        UNION ALL

        SELECT n.id, n.parent_id, n.title, n.url_segment, n.sequence_number, depth - 1 From navigation_node as n
        INNER JOIN navigation_self_and_parents as rn
        ON n.id = rn.parent_id
    )
    SELECT * FROM navigation_self_and_parents
)
```

navigation_node DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[navigation_node](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [title] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
    [url_segment] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [hidden] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [page_id] [int] NULL,
    [parent_id] [int] NULL,
    [sequence_number] [int] NOT NULL,
    [createdOn] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [updatedOn] [datetime] NULL,
    [navigation_type_id] [int] NULL,
    ...snap
```

Comment: What is the type of `url_segment`?

Comment: I've had similar results with this approach to concatenating before. (where it ends up only with the value from one row rather than all) I've never noticed that `datatype` has played a part. Sometimes you need to tweak the query a bit to get the required execution plan. Can you post both plans? (Or you could of course just use XML PATH as you are on SQL Server 2005 which is documented to work) See also http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287515/en-us

Comment: @El Ronnoco updated question with more details.

Comment: @Martin it seems removing the order by clause does indeed have an impact on what results i get back. If you post your comment as answer i'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: What do you get for just `SELECT * FROM navigation_self_and_parents(2813) ORDER BY depth ASC`? Exactly the 3 rows no more no less?

Comment: @cyberwiki yes the result is the reversed set of what I pasted in the question. So exactly 3 no more no less but in the reversed order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This approach to string concatenation does usually work but it isn't guaranteed.

The official line in [the KB article for a similar issue](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287515/en-us) is that "The correct behavior for an aggregate concatenation query is undefined."

There must be some subtle difference between the plans. You can either tweak the query to remove the difference and get the required execution plan or you could/should of course just use `XML PATH` as you are on SQL Server 2005 and this is documented to work.

Comment: @Martin - I haven't seen it fail. The link refers to using functions in aggregate queries, which makes sense. But does that apply here?

Comment: @cyberkiwi - Did you look at the code in the link? It doesn't use any aggregates. `SELECT @Str1 = @Str1 + C1 FROM T1 ORDER BY LTRIM( RTRIM( C1 ) )`

Comment: @Martin - FYI it is `aggregate`ing the text into one variable. The order by involves the functions LTRIM, RTRIM

Comment: @cyberkiwi - Yep. The difference seems to be in where the `compute scalar` ends up. I presume that the OP is getting a similar difference in their plans between the one that needs a cast and the one that doesn't.

Comment: @Martin, @Martijn - Interesting the function doesn't return a `depth` column. It must involve some expression/function there. Maybe `-sequence as depth`? Or has the query been simplified for SO?

Comment: @cyberwiki my bad, pasted the wrong function _and_children instead of _and_parents :)

Comment: @Martijn - It would be useful to post the results of `SET STATISTICS PROFILE ON` for both so we can see the difference (we might not get the same plans as you because of different statistics and different versions)