# Flatten SQL Server Table to a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like:

```
ID  | Value
----------------
 1  | One
 2  | Two
 3  | Three
```

What I need to do is create a single string from these values, in the format:

```
'1: One, 2: Two, 3: Three'
```

I know how to do this using cursors, but it will be used as a column in a view, so it's not really a performant option.
Any pointers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
WITH T(ID,Value) AS
(
SELECT 1, 'One' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Two' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Three' 
)

SELECT  STUFF(
        (SELECT ', ' + CAST(ID as varchar(11)) + ': ' + Value
         FROM T
         FOR XML PATH (''))
     , 1, 2, '')
```

Comment: Thx, XML PATH did the trick. I knew I was missing something, just could not put my finger on it.

Comment: @SWeko - Astander's answer is safer if your data can contain any of `<`, `>`, `&` (and possibly some other characters as well)

Comment: No problem, I'll take care of the details (the real data is actually numeric, so no funny stuff there). I just needed someone to shoud XML PATH to me :)

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at something like

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        ID INT,
        Value VARCHAR(20)
)
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 1,'One'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 2,'Two'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 3,'Three'

SELECT  STUFF(
                (
                    SELECT  ', ' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ': ' + Value
                    FROM    @Table
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE 
               ).value('.','varchar(max)') 
               ,1,2, '' 
          )
```

Comment: This approach is safer than the other two `XML PATH` answers as it deals correctly with XML entitisation but less performant if the data doesn't contain any problematic characters.

Comment: @Martin, I assume this is safer because of the `.value...` construct?

Comment: @Lieven - Yes. My remark on performance was based on [Simon Sabin's comment here](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2006/07/06/871.aspx) "The issue with using the .value is that you invoke the XML Reader operators which aren't the best in terms of performance"

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT STUFF((
    SELECT ' ' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(2)) + ': '+ Value
    FROM   dbo.Table
    FOR    XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, ''
  ) As concatenated_string
```

Answer (score 1):

DECLARE @ans  VARCHAR(max)

SET @ans=''

SELECT @ans = @ans + str(id)+':'+value FROM table

SELECT @ans

Change the max to 8000 if your version of SQL doesn't support it

Comment: [This isn't guaranteed to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780513/varcharmax-acting-weird-when-concatenating-string/4780904#4780904) though probably will!

Comment: It does work, I've used it for quick table to string functionality.

Comment: SWeko-Not sure what you mean, it doesn't loop the rows.   Try it out, the SELECT statement loops the rows and concatenates the fields into the variable

Comment: The edit is ok, this works in a quick and dirty way. Still prefer the XML solution better, though.

Comment: That is the beauty of Stack Overflow, you get multiple answers and can pick the one that is best for you...

Answer (score 0):

I would simply not do this in the database if at all possible. It's not designed for formatting data in a certain way; let the calling application handle that.

In C# (assuming `data` is an instance of SqlDataReader):

```
var l = new List<string>();
while (reader.Read())
    l.Add(string.Format("{0}: {1}", reader[0], reader[1]));
var s = string.Join(", ", l.ToArray());
```