# Invalid Column name for Dynamic SQL with PIVOT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I am trying to get monthly sales for different desserts and pivot them on columns. The column names are defined in `@columns` and shown in the attachment. The error says invalid column names, I have extracted the column names from  `MenuItems` table and are displayed as they are. How can I fix this?

[image]

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
SELECT 
    @columns += QUOTENAME([Name]) + ', '
FROM 
    dbo.MenuItems 
WHERE 
    [GroupCode] = 'Desserts';
SET @columns = LEFT(@columns, LEN(@columns) - 1);
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
PRINT @columns;
SET @sql = '
    WITH monthly_desserts as (
        SELECT 
            YEAR(ord.[LastUpdateDateTime]) AS [Year],
            MONTH(ord.[LastUpdateDateTime]) AS [Month],
            ord.[MenuItemName] AS [ItemName],
            ISNULL(SUM(ord.[Quantity]), 0) AS [Qty], 
            ISNULL(SUM(ord.[Quantity] * ord.[Price]), 0) AS [Revenue]
        FROM
            dbo.Orders ord
        WHERE 
            ord.[MenuItemName] IN (' + @columns + ')
        GROUP BY
            ord.[MenuItemName],
            YEAR(ord.[LastUpdateDateTime]),
            MONTH(ord.[LastUpdateDateTime])
    ) select 
        [Year], 
        [Month],
        ' + @columns + '
    FROM 
        monthly_desserts
    PIVOT (
        SUM([Revenue])
        FOR [ItemName] IN (' + @columns + ')
    ) pvt
    ORDER BY
        [Year] DESC, [Month] DESC
';

execute(@sql);
```

Looking for results in following manner

[image]

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: which RDBMS are you using? MySQL,SQL Server,postgresql,..... . tag it correctly

Comment: Providing text and code instead of images of code helps to get much faster recommendations from the community

Comment: `ord.[MenuItemName] IN (' + @columns + ')` becomes `ord.[MenuItemName] IN ([Strawberry sundae])`. Because of `[]` you are looking for columns with that name. `print @sql` Should always be involved in writing dynamic sql

Comment: Side note: Using variable assignment to concatenate strings (SELECT @Column += ....) is [undocumented and unreliable](https://marc.durdin.net/2015/07/concatenating-strings-in-sql-server-or-undefined-behaviour-by-design/). It does not always work as expected. You should either use STRING_AGG (if using a version that supports it), or use [XML Extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5031297/1048425) to concatenate the rows into a variable

Comment: Please provide sample data (no screenshots) to test your script, then we'll advise accordingly...

Comment: @GarethD  is right, avoid use of undocumented method, additionally try change the size of variable columns from NVARCHAR(MAX) to NVARCHAR(4000) or some reasonable size, because there are some strange behavior previously reported when concatenating in this way, please check the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780513/varcharmax-acting-weird-when-concatenating-string

Comment: ..Or better use undocumented method with caution, sometimes it's easy to use them.